# Intellij IDEA/JBoss EAP 6.3 Configuration Gets Overwritten

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm new to IDEA and have most things working the way I would like, but I needed to add a datasource to my server. Unfortunately, because IDEA uses the standalone.xml to deploy, it overwrites it every time I start it wiping out my change to the datasources. I have tried to add it directly to the file and add it through the management console. Neither is picked up by IDEA. Is there a way to "refresh" IDEA's cache of the configuration file, or a good way to add the data source through IDEA so that is "knows" about the change?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I must have posted too quickly. I see that the adding through the management console actually was the answer, I think. All is good.